# highlighting multiple elements of same name in eagle

Tags: components, eaglecad

Is there a way that I can make eagle highlight only all components with the functionality I choose?

For example, In my circuit, I created a "staple" so I can use a standard staple as a jumper wire, and I figured out that Eagle names them `U$xx` where xx is a number.

If I type in `show U$xx` where xx is a number that matches the number in use (for example if I had a staple named `U$1` and I typed in `show U$1`) then that staple highlights.

I can probably succeed if I typed in `show U$1`, `show U$2`, `show U$3` and I keep going until I get to the highest number, but in my project I could change the number of staples (jumper wires) in my project and the numbering might be off, but they all start with `U$`. So I tried `show U$*` and I tried `show U$[0..n]` where n is the highest number possible and eagle tells me its not found.

Is there a way I can show all staples at once with one simple command? Let's assume their names start with `U$`.

Comment: `show U$*` should work - `*` is used as the wildcard as per `help show`. I've just tried it on one of my designs in Eagle 6.6.0.

Comment: hmm maybe my version doesn't support it. I use eagle 4.1 but I do admit its stable compared to what I read about a newer version of eagle (7?) always crashing.